# Is that possible to count all row base on one value, and get the column name with largest count (mysql)?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to count all rows base on the category column, example below, category apple has two rows, so get the the category name apple. Thank you.

```
id  user_id   category
1    2         apple
2    4        banana
3    6         apple
4    7        berry
```

//Count all rows, apple has two row, the largest count, so then get the the category name apple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Group by` to count the category.

Then order the result set in descending order of the count and select the top 1.

**Query**

```
select t.category
from 
 (
    select category,
    count(category) as cat_count
    from fruits
    group by category
 )t
 order by t.cat_count desc limit 1;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84fd2/2)

If multiple category having same max count. Then,

**Query**

```
select t.category
from
(
   select category,
   count(category) as cat_count
   from fruits
   group by category
)t
where t.cat_count = 
(
   select count(category) as cat_count
   from fruits
   group by category
   order by count(category) desc
   limit 1
);
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43fe2/6)

Answer (score 0):

Add limit if you need top 1,2,3 like that **limit X** x is 1,2,3

```
 Select count(*) as total,category from table group by category from table order by count(*) desc
```

Comment: OP needs the category name having the maximum count.